# Text overlays of composed video doesn’t match UI

Tags: swiftui, avmutablecomposition

I have a SwiftUI view on top of a video view, which has a standard size, full width, and almost full height (always portrait). The video's ratio varies. The SwiftUI view has a `Text` that the user can drag-and-drop and scale its font.

```swift
struct EditPostLyricsTextView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewModel: EditPostView.ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        TitleView(
            text: viewModel.currentLyricsText,
            font: UIFont(name: viewModel.lyricsMetadata.fontName, size: 17)!,
            fontSize: 25 * viewModel.lyricsMetadata.fontScale,
            alignment: viewModel.lyricsMetadata.alignment,
            textColor: viewModel.lyricsMetadata.color
        )
        .padding(50)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        .overlay {
            Color.responsiveClear
        }
        .position(viewModel.lyricsMetadata.coordinates)
        .gesture(
            MagnificationGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    let delta = value / viewModel.lyricsMetadata.fontScale
                    let newScale = viewModel.lyricsMetadata.fontScale * delta
                    
                    viewModel.lyricsMetadata.fontScale = min(2, max(1, newScale))
                }.simultaneously(with: DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        viewModel.lyricsMetadata.coordinates = value.location
                    }).simultaneously(with: TapGesture()
                        .onEnded(viewModel.presentEditLyricsView))
        )
        .clipped()
    }
}
```

Then, I need to export it with the text overlays, ensuring that the position and size must match at all video resolutions.

```swift
struct TextSegment {
    let text: String
    let startTime: Double
    let endTime: Double
    let originalCanvasSize: CGSize
    let padding: CGFloat
    var coordinates: CGPoint
    let color: UIColor
    let fontName: String
    let fontSize: CGFloat
    let alignment: NSTextAlignment
}

struct VideoEditorService {
    func addTextOverlaysToVideo(videoURL: URL, textSegments: [TextSegment], completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
        let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL)
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        
        let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: videoAsset.duration)
        
        guard let videoTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first,
              let compositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        
        do {
            if let audioAssetTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first,
               let compositionAudioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(
                withMediaType: .audio,
                preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) {
                try compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(
                    timeRange,
                    of: audioAssetTrack,
                    at: .zero)
            }
            
            try compositionTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: videoTrack, at: .zero)
            let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(propertiesOf: videoAsset)
            
            let overlayLayer = CALayer()
            overlayLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: videoComposition.renderSize)
            
            textSegments.forEach { segment in
                addText(
                    textSegment: segment,
                    to: overlayLayer,
                    videoSize: videoComposition.renderSize
                )
            }
            
            // Apply the overlay layer with animations
            let parentLayer = CALayer()
            
            parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoComposition.renderSize.width, height: videoComposition.renderSize.height)
            parentLayer.addSublayer(overlayLayer)
            
            videoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: overlayLayer, in: parentLayer)
            
            // Export the video
            exportVideo(
                originalVideoURL: videoURL,
                composition: composition,
                videoComposition: videoComposition,
                completion: completion
            )
        } catch {
            print("Failed to add text overlay: \(error)")
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
    
    private func addText(textSegment: TextSegment, to layer: CALayer, videoSize: CGSize) {
        let originalWidth = textSegment.originalCanvasSize.width - textSegment.padding
        let maxWidth = (originalWidth * videoSize.width) / textSegment.originalCanvasSize.width
        
        let fontSize = min((videoSize.width * textSegment.fontSize) / textSegment.originalCanvasSize.width, (videoSize.height * textSegment.fontSize) / textSegment.originalCanvasSize.height)
        let standardRatio = (textSegment.originalCanvasSize.width / textSegment.fontSize) * (textSegment.originalCanvasSize.height / textSegment.fontSize)
        
        let attributedText = NSAttributedString(
            string: textSegment.text,
            attributes: [
                .font: UIFont(name: textSegment.fontName, size: fontSize) ?? .defaultHeavy(size: fontSize),
                .foregroundColor: textSegment.color,
            ]
        )
        
        let textLayer = CATextLayer()
    

        
            textLayer.string = attributedText
    //        textLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            textLayer.alignmentMode = textSegment.alignment == .center ? .center : textSegment.alignment == .left ? .left : .right
            textLayer.isWrapped = true
            textLayer.truncationMode = .end
            textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
            textLayer.shouldRasterize = true
            textLayer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
            textLayer.opacity = 0
            
            let textSize = attributedText.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: .infinity),
                                                       options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading],
                                                       context: nil).size
            let height = ceil(textSize.height)
            print("maxWidth", maxWidth)
            print("textSize", ceil(textSize.height))
            print("textSize", textSegment.coordinates)
            print("textSize", videoSize)
            
            let normalisedX = ((videoSize.width * textSegment.coordinates.x) / textSegment.originalCanvasSize.width) - (maxWidth / 2)
            let normalisedY = (videoSize.height - (videoSize.height * textSegment.coordinates.y) / textSegment.originalCanvasSize.height) - (height / 2)
            
            textLayer.frame = CGRect(
                x: normalisedX,
                y: normalisedY,
                width: maxWidth,
                height: height
            )
            
            textLayer.displayIfNeeded()
            
            let startVisible = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
            
            startVisible.fromValue = 0.0
            startVisible.toValue = 1.0
            startVisible.duration = 0.05 // for appearing in duration
            startVisible.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero + textSegment.startTime
            startVisible.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            startVisible.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
            textLayer.add(startVisible, forKey: "startAnimation")
            
            let endVisible = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
            endVisible.fromValue = 1.0
            endVisible.toValue = 0.0
            
            endVisible.duration = 0.05 // for disappearing in duration
            endVisible.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero + textSegment.endTime
            endVisible.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
            endVisible.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            textLayer.add(endVisible, forKey: "endAnimation")
            
            layer.addSublayer(textLayer)
        }
    }
```

I've tried to make everything proportional, from the font size to the coordinates. But, although there are times that the sizes look identical to the SwiftUI's view, other times the exported video can have an extra line.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How do you go to VideoEditorService in the app?

Comment: In the line that starts with textSegments.forEach { segment in, you are not setting the position of and the size of textLayer in the addText guy.  That's all you get from me.